# Issue with @azure/openai npm package - Empty toolCalls in response

Tags: openai-api, function-call, azure-openai, gpt-4

I am currently using the @azure/openai npm package for Node.js to interact with the GPT-4 model. I have noticed that the toolCalls in the response are empty, even though I have included tools in my request.

Code:

```js
const getCurrentWeather = {
  name: 'get_current_weather',
  description: 'Get the current weather in a given location',
  parameters: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      location: {
        type: 'string',
        description: 'The city and state, e.g. San Francisco, CA',
      },
      unit: {
        type: 'string',
        enum: ['celsius', 'fahrenheit'],
      },
    },
    required: ['location'],
  },
};

const messages = [{ role: 'user', content: 'What is the weather like in Glasgow Scotland?' }];
const options = {
  tools: [
    {
      type: 'function',
      function: getCurrentWeather,
    },
  ],
};
client.getChatCompletions(deploymentIdBest, messages, options).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Expected Behavior:
Ofcourse we expect something like this in the response:

```json
{'role': 'assistant',
 'content': None,
 'tool_calls': [{'id': 'call_o7uyztQLeVIoRdjcDkDJY3ni',
   'type': 'function',
   'function': {'name': 'get_current_weather',
    'arguments': '{\n  "location": "Glasgow, Scotland",\n  "format": "celsius"\n}'}}]}
```

Actual Behavior:
This is the full response from the azure/openai client (tried both gpt-4-turbo and gpt-35-turbo):

```json
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-8fr5PAthe2uTIHVjd8mcy7pOMkrx5",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "model": "gpt-4",
  "usage": {
    "promptTokens": 172,
    "completionTokens": 22,
    "totalTokens": 194
  },
  "created": "1970-01-20T17:36:26.203Z",
  "promptFilterResults": [
    {
      "promptIndex": 0,
      "contentFilterResults": {}
    }
  ],
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "finishReason": "tool_calls",
      "contentFilterResult": {
        "error": {
          "code": "content_filter_error",
          "message": "The contents are not filtered"
        }
      },
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "toolCalls": []
      },
      "contentFilterResults": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

@azure/openai versions in question: 1.0.0-beta.10 and 1.0.0-alpha.20240104.1

Comment: It is something recent, and I am experiencing it myself in a solution that was working perfectly previously. In the result the toolCalls array is empty with the nodejs SDK. My hunch this is a wireformat mismatch with the ever evolving SDK + API. Trying to validate this now with a direct REST invoke.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the OpenAI service rather than the nodejs OpenAI SDK.
I've checked, and the REST interface has the same issue. It is a recent change, I have positive memories of this working 2-3 weeks ago.

Someone already reported this to the Azure team here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/28343

UPDATE:
This has been fixed now, the issue was related with just a few service regions.